# mysql copy table?

Tags: mysql

I am using

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO imaegs_backup SELECT * FROM images");
```

in order to copy the information for the images table to the images_backup table. On the images table I have:

```
id     name      link

1      name1     www.aaa.com/1
2      name2     www.aaa.com/2
3      name3     www.aaa.com/3

5      name5     www.aaa.com/5
```

as you can see id number 4 is missing from the images table. and when I am coping the tables I am getting the same result in table images_backup(which is expected). How can I copy the images table to the images_backup and I want the result to be something like this:

```
id     name      link

1      name1     www.aaa.com/1
2      name2     www.aaa.com/2
3      name3     www.aaa.com/3
4      name5     www.aaa.com/5
```

as you can see in row 4 there is name5 and link to image 5.
Note: the id column is set to auto increment, but I can change that.

Comment: This really defeats the purpose of auto increments. Are you sure you want to do this? What do you want to do this for in the first place?

Comment: I want to select the most viewed images on the website. For now I am only stuck with this problem because I do not want to have empty id row.

Comment: Why not? What's wrong with it? Auto increments are *designed* to have missing elements where a deletion has taken place

Comment: I have image rotation function in php that is totally dependable on the id. If there is one id row missing, the rotation will stop.

Comment: then you should probably rewrite that function so it doesn't depend on the ID that badly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the table you're inserting into has an auto-incrementing ID, then just specify two columns; the auto-incrementing field will take care of the value itself:

```
INSERT INTO images_backup (name, link) 
SELECT name, link FROM images ORDER BY id
```